# Cmd err “|” was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i receive the message "Error: “|” was unexpected at this time batch script
" when i run the code below:

```
@set CheckAccount=FOR /F "tokens=3" %A IN ('net user UserName /domain^|Findstr /ic: "active"') do SET Active=%A
%CheckAccount%
| was unexpected at this time.
```

Even when i change `"active"` to `active`. I can't seem to echo `CheckAccount` without getting that error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an extra level of parsing because of the intermediate variable `CheckAccount` being used. This requires escaping the problem characters twice.

```
@set CheckAccount=FOR /F "tokens=3" %A IN ('net user UserName /domain^^^|Findstr /ic:"active"') do SET Active=%A
```

The `set` command will parse and store `^^^|` as `^|` into `CheckAccount`, then expanding `%CheckAccount%` will leave just the pipe `|`.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Removed the extra space after `/ic:`, thanks @Squashman for pointing that out.

Comment: Could also quote surround the defining of the variable and use one ^. Also need to remove the space after the `FINDSTR` options.  Should just be `/ic:"active"`

Comment: @Squashman Fixed the `/ic:` part, missed it when I copied the line over. And you're right about quoting the whole `set` argument, only that would require also escaping the other `"` quotes, and I chose to keep it closest to the original command line.

Comment: @dxiv, you don't have to escape the double quotes.  I tested from the command prompt and a batch file and it works both ways without escaping the quotes.

Comment: @Squashman In this case, yes, but in general surrounding it in quotes toggles the escaping requirement inside nested quotes e.g. `set "a=b|b "c^&c" d<d"`. Escaping the leading quote does not change it e.g. `set ^"a=b^|b "c&c" d^<d"` but in this case that wouldn't make a difference, anyway. And escaping (some of the) inside quotes becomes tricky to follow e.g. `set "a=b|b "c^&c^" d^<d"`.